# Exchange 2013 Email address could not be found

Tags: exchange

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 R2, with Microsoft Exchange 2013 CU9 installed on it. The Exchange installation routes mail happily enough, and has been stable up until recently. The only change made was to add another accepted domain to the server, and add the new domain to the email address policy so that it filters out to the users.

Following the change, several users are beginning '550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found' errors.
Eset AntiSpam has marked the email as 'clean, is OK', so it's not tripping the primary antispam filter - though Exchange antispam could still be an issue.

As far as I can ascertain, the error lies in a corrupt address entry. The message references the destination as being the fully expanded AD  path, rather than the direct address - see example:
IMCEAEX-_O=%orgname%_OU=FIRST+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=%firstname%+2E%lastinitial%@%primary.domain.extension%

Has anyone else come up with a concrete fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem:  Users are trying to send to a LegacyExchangeDN value (X500 address).

Fix/workaround: Deleting autocomplete addresses in Outlook should resolve this.

Problem: The X500 address listed contains characters that didn't translate correctly somehow.  <kbd>+</kbd> is an indicator of some sort of translation occurring.`+20` is equal to a `space`.  (This could be a false symptom, keep reading...)

Fix: This could be from a number of different sources. Look at the user objects and see if they have X500 addresses assigned.  In this case I would prefer to look in Active Directory, but the info should be exposed in Exchange Admin Center as well.

You say that you added a new domain to the Exchange server, and that's when the "cohabitation" issues started.  I recommend you reference this technet article about adding a second Authoritative domain in Exchange:  [Configure Exchange to accept mail for multiple authoritative domains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996314(v=exchg.150).aspx). It is possible there's a configuration missing.

Comment: That's the guide I used as a reference. The additional domain just provides aliases. 
There shouldn't be anything legacy. All the users are using Outlook 2013, and it was a fresh install of Exchange 2013 on setting up the company - nothing old was brought across. Exchange has no X500 address listed as assigned, and AD shows nothing there either.

Comment: http://msexchangeguru.com/2012/03/15/x500/ I think you need to look at the X500 addresses. :\